# .net core 2.1 redis cache in azure functions v2

Tags: redis, azure-functions, stackexchange.redis

Am reading people having trouble with using rediscache in azure functions on consumption plan.

please advise best practice for using caching in azure functions 2.0

my rediscache will be used by api's as well as azure functions (consumption plan). since connection object is supposed to be singleton and reused in case of functions on every request it will create new connection will this create problems ?

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware of the various limitations for [Azure Redis Cache performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-faq#azure-redis-cache-performance) per pricing tier, especially SSL and Non-SSL connections per second. Please also be aware of the benefits + behaviors of using the [StackExchange.Redis configuration options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-faq#what-do-the-stackexchangeredis-configuration-options-do).